# Uploaded ZIP archive. Convert only PNG to JPEG in PHP

Tags: php, zip, png, jpeg

For the life of me, I cant figure out how to code part of this process:

**Ive Already Completed These Steps:**
 1. Upload ZIP archive (containing only photos in gif, png, and jpg)
 2. Unpack to folder
 3. Scan folder for filenames + file extentions

**I Need Help With:**
 4. Convert only PNG to JPG

Any help would be appreciated!

### Brandon

EDIT:
Does this make sense?

```
$directory = "../images/ilike/goldfish/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image)  
{  
$pic = imagecreatefrompng($directory);  
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));  
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));  
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE); 
imagecopy($bg, $pic, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image))  
imagedestroy($image);  
imagejpeg($bg, $image . ".jpg", 100);  
ImageDestroy($bg);  
}
```

Comment: That's quite a broad question and a lot of code that'd need to be written here. What particular part of this process are you stuck with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take in the file from a form as usual, open it with http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php and use http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.extractto.php to extract the files to an empty folder. Then using the PHP standard file handling functions scan filenames that end with .jpg. Load them in with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php and then save them out with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php .

Comment: Do I need an if statement for only opening jpgs?

Comment: Iterating over the array of filenames that the file and folder handling functions gives you and only opening those files that end in .jpg will filter out those that aren't. I'd also suggest checking every file before opening the ZIP and discard the whole thing if it contains anything but jpgs, pngs or gifs.

Comment: I already have it scripted to delete the archive if it contains anything else than the 3 filetypes. Would this work for scanning the directory and converting the PNGs to JPG?

Comment: Yes, this same method (short of the bit about opening the ZIP) would work all the same on any directory.

Comment: Does this make sense?

$directory = "../images/ilike/goldfish/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image)  
{  
$pic = imagecreatefrompng($directory);  
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));  
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));  
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE); 
imagecopy($bg, $pic, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image))  
imagedestroy($image);  
imagejpeg($bg, $image . ".jpg", 100);  
ImageDestroy($bg);  
}

Comment: You should be able to replace everything everything between `$bg` and `ImageDestroy($bg);` with `imagejpeg($bg, $image)`

Answer (score 0):

```
//here we create directory
---------------------------- 
$new_folder=mkdir('C:\\wamp\\www\\TestImage\\uploads\\'.$folder_name, 0777, true);
$path="uploads\\".$folder_name."\\";

//uploading files
-----------------------------
$fileName = $_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["upload_file"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = @$_FILES["upload_file"]["application/zip"];  // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["upload_file"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["upload_file"]["error"]; // 0 = false | 1 = true
$kaboom = explode(".",$_FILES["upload_file"]["name"]); // Split file name into an array using the dot
$fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension


if (!preg_match("/.(zip)$/i", $fileName) ) {
     // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
     //echo "ERROR: Your file was not .zip file";
     echo "Please select image files.Supported format are .Zip</br>"; 
     unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
     #exit();
}

//unzip to specific location
--------------------------------
if(preg_match("/.(zip)$/i", $fileName))
{
$moveResult= move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $fileName);

if($moveResult == true)
{ 
     $zip = new ZipArchive;

     $res = $zip->open($fileName);

    if($res==TRUE)
        {  
            $zip->extractTo($path.$fileName);

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($zip);


            $zip->close();
        } else {
         echo 'failed';
        }

}

unlink($fileName); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
//exit();
}
```

### //function for Convert only PNG to JPG

```
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($originalFile);
        imagejpeg($image, $outputFile, $quality);//$outputFile->define name of output file and  $quality is a number between 0 (best compression) and 100 (best quality)
        imagedestroy($image);

note->refer for <gdlib> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php
```